# Unable to add Column Headers Custom

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

[image]Good Day..
I have a gridview and it is showing columns as shown in diagram above

I would like to replace column names from ID Name Task Total Sale etc

But I am unable to do it

When I give header text, or edit column, it adds the rows from database NOT below the header text

Please Guide

Thanks

This is what Search button does when clicked:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection  strg = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RANA;Initial Catalog=PlacementCellProject;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        //SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strg);
        SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID, name, task, total_sale, owner, worker, tdate, payment_status from saloonworkers where tdate between '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "' and '" + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString() + "' ", strg);
        DataTable sd=new DataTable();
        sdf.Fill(sd);
        dataGridView1.DataSource=sd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
    }
```

And this is OnLoad initializatoin:

```
    public Form6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox3.Text = "";
        showworkers();
        ownershare();
        workershare();
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "I";

       //  dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].HeaderText = "I";
      /*dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ID", "I");

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            string header = dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        }*/

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you binding data you can use property "DisplayName".

```
[DisplayName("Name")]

public string FirstName {get;set;}
```

Also you can onload page put header text like this

```
grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Name";
```

OK, you try first in OnLoad method change headers which not exist, add your code from button to onload and next change yours headers. FIRST add datasource next change headers.

Comment: If you want to say form_load, it not works, and Onload event is not there in grid..

Comment: As per your query, error is:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: So add it after load datasource. You need first add datasource next change headers. Columns index starting from 0. So if your "ID" column is first, it really is on index 0.

Answer (score 0):

After binding the `DataSource` to `DataGridView`. Try change the `HeaderText`.

```
sampleGridView.DataSource = stu;
sampleGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
```

Comment: I did.. There column was added but when I run it shows like:

ID ID Task Sale etc

Means it shows all columns plus the added one

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

you will set column name before databind.
i hope it's help you

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BindGrid()
        {
            string constring = @"Data Source=.\SQL2005;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User id = sa;password=pass@123";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);

                            //Set AutoGenerateColumns False
                            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                            //Set Columns Count
                            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;

                            //Add Columns
                            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "CustomerId";
                            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Customer Id";
                            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "CustomerID";

                            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Contact Name";
                            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Name";
                            dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "ContactName";

                            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Country";
                            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Country";
                            dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Country";
                            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Please use given code.i am sure it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

First you need load datasource and next change headertext

```
sampleGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
```